# Client-Server Socket connection works when client socket connects to local IP and does not work with a global IP. (over 4G connection)

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, client-server

Hi I am new to programming and here I am trying to create a Client-Server Socket connection using Java on Android Studio, client socket on one Android phone, server socket on another. Code works regardless of the port I use when I connect both phones on the same router, and use internal IP (192.168.1.4) for client socket instead of global IP (183.90.37.22). However, if I were to turn on 4G connection and use global IP in my code, client socket cannot connect to the server socket on the other phone. However when port 80 was used, I managed to see the toasts showing till "Message Sent" **ALTHOUGH** no message/toasts showed in the phone coded with the server socket. I very much appreciate all the help I can get and it would be great if a thorough explanation on how I should assign TCP ports to client & server sockets could be given! =)

Client Socket is presented first:

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MessageSenderThread messageSender = new MessageSenderThread("messageSender");
            messageSender.start();
        }
    });

}

class MessageSenderThread extends Thread {
    private String threadName;
    private Thread t;

    MessageSenderThread(String s) {
        threadName = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            showToast("Connecting to server...");
            Socket socket = new Socket("183.90.37.22", 80);
            showToast("Connection established");
            OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStreamWriter);
            printWriter.println("MESSAGE");
            printWriter.flush();
            showToast("Message sent");

            outputStream.close();
            outputStreamWriter.close();
            printWriter.close();
            socket.close();
            showToast("Socket closed");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            showToast("Connection FAILED");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        if (t == null) {
            t = new Thread(this, threadName);
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Server side of the code is presented below:

```
MessageReceiverThread messageReceiverThread = new MessageReceiverThread("messageReceiver");
messageReceiverThread.start();

class MessageReceiverThread extends Thread {
    private String threadName;
    private Thread t;

    MessageReceiverThread(String s) {
        threadName = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);
                showToast("Server is listening...");
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                showToast("Connection established");
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String message = bufferedReader.readLine();

                showToast(message);
                inputStream.close();
                inputStreamReader.close();
                bufferedReader.close();
                socket.close();
                serverSocket.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            showToast("Connection FAILED");
        }
    }
```

Comment: 'Cannot connect' is not a problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Your mobile provider blocks incoming connections.

So it does not make sense running a server on a device that is unreachable.

Comment: Thanks for replying! How then do web servers send HTTP response back to users if mobile providers block incoming connections? And why did port 80 work as stated above?

Comment: If webservers send something back as anwer to a request from a browser then that is no incoming connection. The incoming connection was arready done by the client browser connecting to the webserver. That connection came in on the server computer. So clients on your phone can connect to the internet.

Comment: The picture is clearer to me now. So if my client socket first establishes a connection with the server socket, then onwards to-and-fro data can be sent from client to server and vice versa? 

Adding on, I also came across NAT traversal. Is there a need for NAT traversal if I were to want to develop, say a messaging app? Or can I rely on client sockets to always initiate a connection?